# Deploy fails due to BeanCreationException for Activiti Process

Tags: activiti

Out of nowhere I am suddenly unable to deploy a war file to my production server. Given the difference between this deployment file and the previous one, I decided to redeploy the previous one to save on downtime but the previous one will no longer deploy either. A server restart also failed to fix the problem.... so currently part of my production environment is down.
This is the error I am getting:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'top4ApplicantProcess': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

and the offending lines in our code are

```
ProcessDefinitionQuery definitionQuery = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery().processDefinitionKey( processKey );
List< ProcessDefinition >list = definitionQuery.list();
ProcessDefinition processDefinition = list.get( 0 );
```

I have had nothing to do with Activiti before, and so have no idea where to even start. Where are the process definitions stored? I'm guessing somehow the one with this process key is missing.

**Update:** whatever server, even pointing to our test database, I still get the same error. I even tried deploying a 2 month old build on different server that hadn't been up since then, and it gives the same exception. Are there any cloud dependencies etc that could cause this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Neil

Comment: well, you can do a check before accessing the element in the list before the offending line

Comment: Thanks, but I've already removed the process key from the config file just to get it to deploy - my real problem isn't that I can't deploy, it is that I can't deploy with that process any longer